# jQuery mobile slider - Using just a small part of jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I've built a page that works well in mobile without using any jQuery mobile. I wanted to use just a part of jQuery mobile because I like the way their slider widget works.

The problem is that when I apply the jQuery Mobile framework to my page it just applies everywhere and messes everything up. I only want to use the slider. I tried downloading a build that only included the Slider part, but it didn't work. I wasn't really sure what to include in the build that would make the Slider work without effect the rest of my page.

Does anyone have any success in just pulling out the parts of jQuery mobile to use the slider without effecting the rest of our content?

If using just a small part of jQuery isn't feasible, does anyone know of a plug-in that will offer a similar slider that will work well in desktop and mobiles?

Comment: Use custom build offered by JQM choose widgets you want to use only. http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution on my own.

The jQuery Mobile build maker is down at the moment. Anyway, I found this plugin:

http://refreshless.com/nouislider/

I think it looks nicer than the jQuery one and works just as good or better. It's really easy to implement even for beginners like me and has some nice features.